# jump to named anchor with javascript

Tags: javascript, codeigniter, anchor

I have a php (codeigniter) program that displays all the finished projects of and engineering company. I can click the detail page and from there I can click a link to go back to the overview page. To avoid starting at the top of the list again I would like to jump to the project I cam from.
It seems easy but it gives me problems. I found this solution on the Internet that works with Chrome but not with Firefox and IE:

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
    function moveWindow (){window.location.hash="a13";}
</script>
<body onload="moveWindow()">
.
.
.
<a name="a13"></a>
```

The content of the anchor gets dynamically generated by PHP. As I said it works in Chrome only. IE says something like undefined function `moveWindow` when I go in debug mode.

Answer (score 4):

You can attach a function to the details click that change the URL to currentURL#yourID and then change it to the final URL. This way, currentURL#yourID will be stored in the history of the browser and going back will get you to the right anchor.

Something like (assuming you use jQuery and your IDs are on the `<a>`):

```
$(document).ready( function() {
    $('#yourlist a').click( function(e) {
       e.preventDefault();
       window.location = '#'+$(this).attr('id');
       window.location = this.href; // intentionally not using jQuery ;-)
    });
});
```

The HTML would look like:

```
<ul id="yourlist">
    <li><a href="details_page_for_item_1.html" id="a1">Item 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="details_page_for_item_2.html" id="a2">Item 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="details_page_for_item_3.html" id="a3">Item 3</a></li>
</ul>
```

Not tested...

Comment: In my overview list I use named anchors for example <a name="a13"><a>. When I go back from my detailpage I use a <a href=[url] ... which triggers a PHP controller which in turn builds the HTML page.

Comment: Where should I use the function you suggested? Would it not be better to use a <body onload="jumptoanchor()" function as I have now? As you see I am still not an expert in this field and need some hand holding. Thank you again. I appreciate your support.

Comment: Don't use "name" atribute, it's deprecated and non semantic. Just put IDs on your links or the container of your section. I've edited my answer to show how to listen to the click event when the DOM is ready, you can load jquery lib before and include this in the HEAD of your page or load it as another external script. Further explaintations would require too much time, sorry. You need to learn a bit more about HTML and JS before being able to just being helped and not totally assisted (no offense!)